# initialise Row in WebDataGrid

Tags: c#-4.0, netadvantage

`protected void GridFill(IList ListePointAcces)
        {
            grdRows.Rows.Clear();
            UltraGridRow row = null;
            // Row row = null;
            UltraGridRow ssrow = null;

```
        foreach (Salle salle in meSalle.Selectionner("LIBELLE"))
        {
            row = new UltraGridRow(new object[] { salle.Site().LIBELLE, salle.LIBELLE });

            row.Key = salle.IDSALLE.ToString();

            foreach (PointAcces pta in ListePointAcces)
            {
                if (pta.Salle.IDSALLE != salle.IDSALLE)
                    continue;

                ssrow = new UltraGridRow(new object[] { pta.CODE, pta.LIBELLE, pta.LOGNAME, pta.COMMENTAIRE });
                ssrow.Key = pta.IDPOINTACCES.ToString();

                row.Rows.Add(ssrow);
            }

            if (row.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                grdRows.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: my code is it and i want to
1st initialize "row" and "ssrow"
2nd create a news objects "row" and "ssrow"
which they are all in webdatagrid.i'm using NetAdvantage(Infragistics)V12.2

Comment: an underlined error message says me that "the type or namespace UltraGridRow is mistake" and i want to now what is his equivalent in WebDataGrid.Thanks you for your helps

Comment: what is the question here? please edit your submission to clarify what you would like to know.

Comment: I'm migrating from oldest controls Infragistics to the news controls Infragistics NetAdvantageV12.2.UltraGridRow is a property of an old control UltraWebGrid that permits to create a new row likely in my code.my question is that:what is the equivalent of UltraGridRow in WebDataGrid? if can i say it WebDataGrid is the new UltraWebGrid.i hope that you have understood my question.thanks you

Comment: please edit the original question and reply in the comments